# Woocommerce resize existing product images

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, images

We discover that our Single Product images as set in Woocommerce> Setting > Products > Display are set to big. Single Product Image: 500 ×750px xHard Crop

I have tested plugin regenerate thumbnails but that does not work on the product images.
Also test plugins Resize-image-after-upload. But that plugin does it for all images if bigger then a certain size. So not to use either.
Try to get a plugin or functions.php code to re-size all existing product images to the right dimension. Without luck.

Question: Do you know a plugin or php code for functions.php that does resize all full product images?

Would be very helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use this one for rebuild thumbnails: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/

Comment: Hi this is not a solution. I have ask for products not for thumbnail images. See "plugin regenerate thumbnails does not work on the product images".

Comment: Strange, I've always used it to rebuild product images, since they use the same structure.

Comment: You're right. I forget to delete the cache. Via ftp is see all images are changed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked  :)

Comment: downvoted as link only answers to external resources are not actual answers

Answer (score -1):

Theme authors can now declare image sizes via the `add_theme_support` function. Declaring image sizes this way will take priority over any other settings and also hide the image settings section in the admin area.

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', array(
    'thumbnail_image_width' => 150,
    'single_image_width' => 322,
) );
```

Comment: that do not help with existing images